# Check if list of object is true if is redirect if not throw error warning

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi i need to check if login and password is correct in controller if is i want redirect to index page if not throw error warning in browser. But problem is i dont know how to cast list of object to boolean. And also i dont know how to change text of button via controller like this: `button1id.Text = "User or password is in correct not found";`  It is giving me error. Please can you help me ?

in if it is giving me this error :

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SmartAdvertising.Entities.Login>' to 'bool'

and in else is giving me this error:

> Error  2   The name 'button1id' does not exist in the current context

LoginController :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View("Login", "_LayoutLogin");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string uzivatel, string heslo)
{
    List<Login> list = LoginServiceLayer.Instance.SelectByJmenoHeslo(uzivatel, heslo);
    if (list)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Index");  
    }
    else
    {
        button1id.Text = "User or password is in correct not found"; 
    }
}
```

function from database layer which i use in controller:

```
public List<Login> SelectByJmenoHeslo(string jmeno, string heslo)
{
    string passwords = e.encryption(heslo);
    string queryString = "SELECT jmeno, heslo from Login where (jmeno = '" + @jmeno + "') AND (heslo = '" + @passwords + "');";  
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jmeno", "");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwords", "");
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<Login> login = new List<Login>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Login l = new Login();
            l.jmeno = reader[0].ToString();
            l.heslo = reader[1].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("jmeno: " + l.jmeno + " " + "heslo: " + " " + " " + l.heslo);
            login.Add(l);
        }
        reader.Close();
        return login;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        chyba.zapsat_do_souboru(ex.Message);
        Console.OpenStandardOutput();
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @area = "Home", @role = "form" }))
{
    <input id="textinput" name="jmeno" type="text" placeholder="login" class="form-control input-md" required="">

    <input id="textinput" name="heslo" type="text" placeholder="heslo" class="form-control input-md" required="">

    <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Login")">
        <input type="submit" id="button1id" value="Pokračovat" name="button1id" class="btn btn-success">
    </a>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to seem harsh, but do you have the slightest idea what you are working with? There are no buttons in Asp.Net MVC, because the View (the V of MVC) has no concept of user controls. And it seems you don't understand what the method you are invoking is going to give you back.

AFAICT, you just could say the login is ok if the method returns one row, so you could just change your line:

```
if (list)
```

to

```
if (list.Count == 1)
```

But still, you are not handling authentication: after the login page the user should be "known" in some way (as an example, with a cookie) to the server.
So you would need also something like:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(list[0]);
```

**If**, that is, you are using forms authentication.
See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

On your else, you would need something like:

```
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Wrong username or password";
    return View();
}
```

And you would need to print a label on your view, exposing the ErrorMessage.

Simply put, your question is too broad and the only proper answer is: grab a good book about Asp.Net MVC (and possibly another one about C# or programming in general) and read it from cover to cover...

**Edit**: I didn't pay particular attention to your database code. It is wrong in so many ways my eyes are bleeding. Seriously, please, get a book.